# NS2のコンパイル時のエラーに関して

Tags: ubuntu

ubuntu16.04でns2(ns-2.34)を使っています。
NS2を再コンパイルするべく以下の手順でコマンドを実行したところ、makeで以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
何がエラーにつながっているのか理解できません。
すみませんがご教授お願いします。

**再コンパイル手順**

```
 ./configure        
 make clean     
 make depend        
 make   ←エラー        
 sudo make install
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
/bin/sh: 1: ../tclcl-1.19/tcl2c++: Permission denied
error writing "stdout": broken pipe
    while executing
"puts "### tcl-expand.tcl: begin expanding $name""
    (procedure "expand_file" line 2)
    invoked from within
"expand_file [file tail $name]"
    ("foreach" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"foreach name $argv {
    set dirname [file dirname $name]
    if {$dirname != "."} {
        cd $dirname
        expand_file [file tail $name]
        cd $startupDir
    } else ..."
    (file "bin/tcl-expand.tcl" line 65)
Makefile:528: ターゲット 'gen/ns_tcl.cc' のレシピで失敗しました
make: *** [gen/ns_tcl.cc] エラー 126
```

○Makefile:528

```
$(GEN_DIR)ns_tcl.cc: $(NS_TCL_LIB)
    $(TCLSH) bin/tcl-expand.tcl tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl @V_NS_TCL_LIB_STL@ | $(TCL2C) et_ns_lib > $@
```

Comment: [既存の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/50627/3060) の続きとなる内容に見えます。情報に更新があるだけなら、まず既存質問の方に情報を追記することを検討してください。

Comment: エラーの1行目で `Permission denied` と出ていますから、実行ユーザや作業ディレクトリ等のアクセス権限を確認してください。 - 参考： [ns2 installation Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19665305/2322778)

Comment: たびたび申し訳ありません。編集履歴を見る限り、誤字の修正等にも該当しない「句点や空行の追加や削除」を繰り返しているだけのように見受けられます。 - "編集するときは1文字変更するだけではなく、投稿が実質的に改善されるようにしてください。細かい些末な編集は推奨されません。" ヘルプ: [質問と回答の編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) / 併せて [質問に誰も回答してくれない場合は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) も参考にしてください。

Comment: 大変失礼いたしました。以後気をつけます。

Answer (score 2):

([minish さんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/51101/3060)、コメントでのやり取りに対する補足です)

サンプルのMakefileでは以下のような記述になっていますが

```
TCLSH   = /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.4
TCL2C   = /usr/local/bin/tcl2c++
```

ご質問の環境にて`dpkg`コマンドで確認した結果、インストールされているファイルは`/usr/bin/tclsh8.4`にあるのが分かったわけですから、その環境に合わせてMakefileの記述を修正する必要があります。
(`tcl2c++`は適当に記載しましたが、こちらも実際の環境を確認のうえ修正してください)

```
TCLSH   = /usr/bin/tclsh8.4
TCL2C   = /usr/bin/tcl2c++
```

コメント欄でも簡単には書きましたが、`/usr/local/bin`にはソースコードからコンパイルしたものなどを置くのが一般的です。一方で、ディストリビューション提供のパッケージでインストールしたものは`/usr/bin/`などに置かれます。

Answer (score 1):

tcl 8.4 のスクリプトを使用して gen/ns_tcl.cc をリダイレクトにより作成しようとしているところでエラーとなっています。

[参考にした ns-2.34 の Makefile](https://github.com/barun-saha/ns2-wimax-bluetooth-wsn/tree/master/ns-2.34) の抜粋です。

```
TCLSH = /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.4
TCL2C = /usr/local/bin/tcl2c++

$(GEN_DIR)ns_tcl.cc: $(NS_TCL_LIB)
    $(TCLSH) bin/tcl-expand.tcl tcl/lib/ns-lib.tcl $(NS_TCL_LIB_STL) | $(TCL2C) et_ns_lib > $@
```

コンパイルするには tcl8.4(/usr/bin/tclsh や /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.4 など) が必要なので、tcl パッケージを導入するなどして、再度 configure してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ＊@＊ -VirtualBox:~/ns-allinone-2.34/ns-2.34$ dpkg -L tcl8.4
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/menu
/usr/share/menu/tcl8.4
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/tcl8.4
/usr/share/doc/tcl8.4/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/tcl8.4/copyright
/usr/share/doc/tcl8.4/README.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/tclsh8.4.1.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/tclsh8.4
/usr/share/doc/tcl8.4/changelog.Debian.gz
回答ありがとうございます。tcl8.4のインストールした時のファイルの一覧は上記の通りでした。/usr/bin/tclsh や /usr/local/bin/tclsh8.4 などにインストールできていないのはなぜでしょうか。よろしければご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: パッケージ作成者が /usr/local/bin ではなく /usr/bin にインストールするようにしているからですね。`configure --help ` を実行して tcl のインストール先を確認できるようなオプションがあれば Makefile を修正してくれるかもしれません。